# How do I implement a non-consuming IntoIterator for a struct with an underlying collection?

Tags: loops, rust, iterator, iteration

Let's say I have a `struct` that has a collection, such as a `Vec` as one of its data members:

```
struct MyCollection {
    data: Vec<i32>
}
```

I want the user of `MyCollection` to be able to iterate over its data without direct access to the `Vec` itself, like so:

```
let x = MyCollection{data:vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]};

for i in &x {
    //...
}
```

However, I'm struggling with implementing the necessary Trait `IntoIterator` for the non-consuming version with `&x`. I have successfully implemented the consuming version:

```
impl std::iter::IntoIterator for MyCollection {
    type Item = i32;
    type IntoIter = std::vec::IntoIter<Self::Item>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        return self.data.into_iter();
    }
}
```

However, this is only usable as follows:

```
for i in x {
    println!("{:?}", i);
}
```

which consumes `x`. Cloning the data is possible, but quite expensive, so I'd like to avoid that.

Here is what I have so far for the non-consuming version, which I based on the [source implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html) of `std::vec::Vec`:

```
impl<'a> std::iter::IntoIterator for &'a MyCollection {
    type Item = &'a i32;
    type IntoIter = std::vec::IntoIter<Self::Item>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        return self.data.into_iter();
    }
}
```

which produces the following compile error:

```
error: mismatched types
error: expected &i32, found i32
note: expected type `std::vec::IntoIter<&i32>`
   found type `std::vec::IntoIter<i32>`
error: expected `std::vec::IntoIter<&i32>` because of return type
```

I have also tried removing the `&'a` of the `type Item` since in my case, the elements of `data` are `Copy`able, but this yields the following:

```
error: cannot move out of `self.data` which is behind a shared reference
error: move occurs because `self.data` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I understand the function wants an `IntoIter` of a vector to references, but I'm unsure how to give it one efficiently. I'm new to Rust, so I'd much appreciate some clarity on the concern. Bonus points if you can also tell me how to create a mutable iterator for write access in the same fashion.

Comment: "Bonus points if you can also tell me how to create a mutable iterator for write access in the same fashion." haha, I will let you that as exercise so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use slice type, your user shouldn't have to know that you inner type is vector. Then, your problem is that you must not use `IntoIter` type, but `Iter` type directly.

Simple example:

```rust
struct MyCollection {
    data: Vec<i32>,
}

impl<'a> std::iter::IntoIterator for &'a MyCollection {
    type Item = <std::slice::Iter<'a, i32> as Iterator>::Item;
    type IntoIter = std::slice::Iter<'a, i32>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.data.as_slice().into_iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyCollection {
        data: vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    };

    for i in &x {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```